# Getting Cell Contents Via XPath for ImportXML()

Tags: xpath, google-sheets

I am trying to scrape data from https://www.snpedia.com/index.php/Rs7136259 to create an automated database of genomic information using google sheets.

I would like to retrieve the odds ratio contained in a table on the page. I have tried to figure out the XPath, but nothing I do works. I copied as XPath from InspectElement but that's returning a #N/A error. The information I am trying to scrape is the "Odds Ratio".

My current query:

```
=importxml(J2,"//*div[@id="mw-content-text"]/table/tr[7]/td")
```

Thanks for your input. I have searched the other links but could not figure it out. Sorry for being so green.

Comment: `//*div` this seem to be invalid expression... You should use `//div` or `//*`

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, `*div` is not valid XPath. Another problem is that you have double quotes inside of double quotes, which is also invalid.

It looks like this works:

```
=importxml(J2,"//*[@id='mw-content-text']/table/tr[7]/td")
```